# ActiveMQ: How to merge the schedulerdb of two ActiveMQ brokers

Tags: activemq-classic, scheduler

We have two independent ActiveMQ brokers running (AMQ 5.11 and 5.14). The 5.14 must replace the 5.11 broker.

Yet, the AMQ 5.11 has still messages in the schedulerDB. How can we migrate the scheduled messages from broker 5.11 into the scheduler of 5.14? The 5.14 already has collected scheduled messages, so we cannot simply replace the files.

Can we merge the schedulerdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you keep the old broker alive and configure a static brigde to the new broker. I.e. all messages that appears on any queue would flow over to the new instance. When all scheduled deliveries are done you should be able to close the old broker. This requires you to keep both brokers alive and disable the transport-connector of the old broker so it won't accept clients.

How to setup a Static bridge:
http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html